# How to display Followers Posts Only in Firebase Database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Hi i Have Structured My Firebase Database as such

```
Root{

     Posts{
           id:postId{
                     postower: USer1 UID,
                     post: Post details,
                     postdate: datepostwasPosted,
                    },
           id:postId2{
                     postower2: USer2 UID,
                     post: Post details,
                     postdate: datepostwasPosted,
                    },
          id:postId3{
                     postowe3r: USer3 UID,
                     post: Post details,
                     postdate: datepostwasPosted,
                    }
        }
   Users{
          user ID : UID{
                     username: username,
                     name: person1 Name
                     Following{
                              user1 UID : UID, 
                              user2 UID : UID, 
                              } 
                      Followers{
                              user1 UID : UID, 
                              }
```

I want to show a feed that only shows how the Posts Made by people the user is following. How do i accomplish this in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: It looks like that case is within range of the `FirebaseIndexRecycledAdapter`: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen